# Unable To open True Type (TTF) font file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, laravel, nginx, fonts

I'm running **Laravel** project on Nginx server, in which I call a python file using below command by passing arguments

```
$result = exec("python3 path/to/file.py $data");
```

In the python file, there is a line of code

```
    font_file = base_path+'/fonts/LiberationMono-Bold.ttf'
    cmd = ["ttf2cxf_stream",
                   "",
                   "-s","5.0",
                   font_file,"STDOUT"]
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

This is giving an error that it can't open the *font file* which is present on that location. The owner of the project is **ubuntu:www-data** and the font file is present in that project. I also tried giving it 777 permission but still no luck.

Now when I run the same command in terminal

```
python3 path/to/file.py "data"
```

It successfully runs without the font file access error.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar issue while using "ttf2cxf_stream" library to open font - ttf files. Please check if `ttf2cxf_stream` exist in `/usr/bin` directory if not then try copying it from `/usr/local/bin/` directory and see if you can run py file through PHP code.